# My Expo Project Crashes in Testflight | SDK 49

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, testflight

I've been trying to deploy the new version of my Expo project that I've been working on for a while. However, while there is no issue in the development environment, the project crashes as soon as it opens in the TestFlight environment. When I check the iOS console, I can't see any meaningful error other than "hermes." I've tried almost everything and have been working on this for three weeks now. I've tried almost all the solutions from those who have experienced a similar issue before, but to no avail. I have released several test versions of the mentioned project before, and they worked without any problems. I am using SDK version 49. Please provide guidance.

I am using expo router.

**IOS Log**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Error: invalid host, js engine: hermes', 
reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Error: invalid host, js engine: hermes, stack:
validate@154167:21
configure@153802:30
createClient@154133:27
anonymous@153583:58
loadModuleImplementation@206:13
guardedLoadModule@137:37
metroRequire@64:91
anonymous@153422:66
loadModuleImplementation@206:13
guardedLoadModule@137:37
metroRequire@64:91
anonymous@153411:65
loadModuleImplementation@206:13
guardedLoadModule@137:37
metroRequire@64:91
anonymous@142296:54
loadModuleImplementation@206:13
guardedLoadModule@137:37
metroRequire@64:91
anonymous@108132:26
loadModuleImplementation@206:13
guardedLoadModule@129:46
metroRequire@64:91
get@107915:26
metroContext@108106:14
loadRoute@74985:32
applyDefaultInitialRouteName@74887:31
fileNodeToRouteNode@74942:40
treeNodeToRouteNode@74973:32
anonymous@74843:32
getTreeNodesAsRouteNodes@74842:20
fileNodeToRouteNode@74931:40
treeNodeToRouteNode@74973:32<…>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "popil",
  "version": "3.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "debugger": "react-native-debugger"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.7",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.18",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "html-entities": "^2.4.0",
    "htmlparser2": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-collapsible-tab-view": "^6.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "^0.0.22",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "yup": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^49.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Popil",
    "slug": "popil",
    "version": "3.1.0",
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/logo-ios.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#18181f"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.popil.popil",
      "bitcode": "Debug"
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 12,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/images/logo-android.png"
      },
      "package": "popil.popil"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "favicon": "./src/assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": []
  }
}
```

**eas.json**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.1.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "node": "18.17.1",
      "channel": "production",
      "prebuildCommand": "prebuild --npm"
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import '@expo/metro-runtime';

import { ExpoRoot } from 'expo-router';
import Head from 'expo-router/head';
import { renderRootComponent } from 'expo-router/src/renderRootComponent';

// @ts-ignore
const ctx = require.context('./src/app', true, /.*/);

export function App() {
  return (
    // @ts-ignore
    <Head.Provider>
      <ExpoRoot context={ctx} />
    </Head.Provider>
  );
}

renderRootComponent(App);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was originating from Reactotron. I disabled Reactotron in the store, and now there are no more issues. The application opened successfully.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  //enhancers: [Reactotron.createEnhancer()],
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
```